# How to migrate a team site with publishing infrastructure enabled under another publishing subsite

Tags: 2013, site-template, export, import

We are using SP2013 standard on-premise. There are 2 existing site collection. Both are built with team site template with publishing infrastructure enabled. The URLs are:

```
http://sharepoint.com/sites/Asite/
http://sharepoint.com/sites/Bsite/
```

I need to move Asite under Bsite like `http://sharepoint.com/sites/Bsite/Asite/`. So I export Asite with Export-SPWeb. Then create a blank subsite using publishing site template as `http://sharepoint.com/sites/Bsite/Asite/`. Finally I use Import-SPWeb to import towards `http://sharepoint.com/sites/Bsite/Asite/`

But it returns error:

> Import-SPWeb : Cannot import site. The exported site is based on the
>   template STS#0 but the destination site is based on the template
>   CMSPUBLISHING#0. You can  import sites only into sites that are based
>   on same template as the exported site.

May I know how to work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario, you have to create the new subsite without any template then import the `Asite` on that url.

```
New-SPWeb -Name "Asubsite" -Url "http://sharepoint.com/sites/Bsite/Asite/"
```

Now run the import command.

Comment: Thanks. I never know it is so easy. The import is done but now all pages under /Bsite/Asite/ are throwing "InvalidPageLayoutException". I checked the pages are using layout "/sites/Asite/_catalogs/masterpage/ASite_PageLayout.aspx". Do you know how to fix?

Comment: I m not sure about it... but if you open a new question with complete detail..someone else will respond....i am afraid as this not scope of question so easily ignored...mark this post as asnwer and start new one.